# Finding the successor of an element in Binary Search tree without parent pointer

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Im trying to implement a method that when given an element will return the successor of the element. I have implemented some helper methods, but cant refer to the parent and dont know how to recurs down the tree properly. In the case where the element has a right subtree I can simply call the smallest method on the right subtree

```
/**
 * NonEmptyBinaryTree - this is a binary search tree that is either an inner node
 * of the tree or a leaf node.  Leaf nodes will have 2 empty nodes attached to 
 * the right and the left subtrees.  Note that the insert and remove operation return 
 * the changed tree and they will generally modify existing trees. 

 */


public class NonEmptyBinaryTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinaryTree<T> {

    T data;     // data of the root node of this tree
    BinaryTree<T> left, right;  // left and right sub-trees


    /**
     * Create a NonEmptyBinaryTree tree with root node.
     * The tree will not have sub-trees.
     * 
     * @param data the data of the root node.
     */
    public NonEmptyBinaryTree(T data) { //Equivalent to BSTree construct.
        this.data = data;
        left = new EmptyBinaryTree<T>();
        right = new EmptyBinaryTree<T>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonEmptyBinaryTree tree = new NonEmptyBinaryTree(7); //Root node
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(10);
    }

    /** 
     * Create a NonEmptyBinaryTree with left and right sub-trees
     * @param data value of the root node
     * @param left sub-tree of the new NonEmptyBinaryTree tree
     * @param right sub-tree of the new NonEmptyBinaryTree tree
     */
    public NonEmptyBinaryTree(T data, BinaryTree<T> left, BinaryTree<T> right) {

        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    /**
     * Insert a new node whose value is d into the existing tree.
     * This function should return the binary tree with d inserted.
     * If the tree has already a node with d, do not create a new node 
     * and return the original tree.
     * 
     * Hint: You can implement insert function recursively. 
     * (Each subtree (left or right) is a tree which has insert function)
     * 
     * @param d data of the new node
     * @return BinaryTree<T> 
     */
    public BinaryTree<T> insert(T d) {
        // TODO: Add your implementation here


        if (this.data == null) { //IF no tree exists, create a new one and assign d to the root
            return new NonEmptyBinaryTree<>(d);

        }

        if (this.data.equals(d)) { //If root is the same just return the tree
            return this;
        }

        if (d.compareTo(this.data) > 0 ) { //If its greater than the data, go down thr right subtree
            this.right = this.right.insert(d);
            return new NonEmptyBinaryTree<>(data, left, right);
        }

        else  { //If less than make the trees left insert the node
            this.left = this.left.insert(d);
            return new NonEmptyBinaryTree<>(data, left, right);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T successor(T element){
        if (data == null) return null;
        else return;

    }


    /**
     * This function will find the biggest node in a tree.
     */
    @Override
    public T biggest() {
        if (right.isEmpty()) return data;
        else return right.biggest();
    }

    /**
     * This function will find the smallest node in a tree.
     */
    @Override
    public T smallest() {
        if (left.isEmpty()) return data;
        else return left.smallest();
    }


    /**
     * Find whether a specific data is in the tree or not.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean find(T d) {
        if (data == d) return true;
        else if (d.compareTo(data) < 0) return left.find(d);
        else return right.find(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "without parent pointer"?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Nodes do not have a parent value attached to them

Comment: *Observation 1:* Since there is no guarantee that `compareTo` is consistent with `equals`, both your `insert` and `find` methods are wrong. `data` and `d` should only be considered equal when `compareTo` returns `0`, so using `equals` in `insert` and `==` in `find` are both wrong. Using `==` in `find` is definitely wrong.

Comment: *Observation 2:* Code consistency makes code easier to follow and reduces coding errors, so testing `compareTo(...) > 0` in `insert` but `compareTo(...) < 0` in `find` is inconsistent. You should change the code to compare the same way in both. --- Also, there is no need for `else` if the true-block returns unconditionally.

Comment: *Observation 3:* To find out how to find the next value (node) in a Binary Search Tree, try a web search for e.g. [`BST next`](https://www.google.com/search?q=BST+next). It's amazing how many questions already have answers out there. All you need to do is look for them, so please do your **research** and look now.